# Issues using the ember data fragments while trying to load child data fragments on demand

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on a use case something like this :

```
var Contact = DS.Model.extend({
 firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  addresses : DS.hasManyFragments('address'),
  phones : DS.hasManyFragments('phone'),
  interactions : DS.hasManyFragments('interaction')
 });
```

Contact can have one or more addresses , phones and interactions. 
However my use case restricts me from load the whole contact record at one ago.

what i am trying to do is load addresses , phones and interaction on demand.
So initially only the contact record with firstname and lastname gets loaded.

I make an call from my Contact controller like :   return this.store.find('contact',1);
which returns me 
         {"contacts":{"id":1,"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Smith"}}.

Now later i want to get all the addresses related to contacts/1.
      var addresses =   this.store.find('address',{contactId:1});
I get a JSON response

```
{"addresses":[{"id":"200","street":"6262 Sunset Drive","city":"Miami","state":"Zip"}]}
```

As soon as it gets this response back in controller the application errors out.

I get this error in the logs:

```
  Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: `interval-intl-ember-clii@model:address:` does not appear to be an ember-data model.
```

My question is it possible to use data Fragments to get child objects on demand and attach to the parent object or do i have to get the whole contact object at one go (which i am reluctant to do as i might impact performance )

I am using data fragments as persistence of the child objects  is managed completely through the parent object

Comment: Ember Data now supports [embedded records](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html). Please use `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`.

Comment: But while using this wont i have to handle persistence of child models separately. like in the above case wont i have to save the phone and address separately as well to keep the ember data in sync with the server. i need a mechanism to just save the Contact object and not worry about phones and address.

Comment: If you tell `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` to serialize whole records, saving Contact record also sends Phones and Addresses records to server in one request. Please read the documentation.